# Accessing Azure Storage Blob from an AKS cluster

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-aks

A little context: I'm having to migrate a project from AWS, where I'm currently using ECS, to Azure, where I'll be using AKS since their ACS (ECS equivalent) is deprecated.

This is a regular Django app, with its configuration variables being fetched from a `server-config.json` hosted on a private S3 bucket, the EC2 instance has the correct role with `S3FullAccess`,

I've been looking into reproducing that same behavior but with `Azure Blob Storage` instead, having achieved no success whatsoever :-(.

I tried using the `Service Principal` concept and adding it to the `AKS Cluster` with `Storage Blob Data Owner` roles, but that doesn't seem to work. Overall it's been quite the frustrating experience - maybe I'm just having a hard time grasping the right way to use the permissions/scopes. The fact that the `AKS Cluster` creates its own resource group is something unfathomable - but I've attempted attaching the policies to it as well, to no avail. I then moved onto a solution indicated by Microsoft.

I managed to bind my AKS pods with the correct `User Managed Identity` through their indicated solution [`aad-pod-identity`](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/), but I feel like I'm missing something. I assigned `Storage Blob Data Owner/Contributor` to the identity, but still, when I enter the pods and try to access a Blob (using the python sdk), I get a `resource not found` message.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible at all? Or will I have to change to a solution using `Azure Keyvault`/something along those lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first off all, you can use [AKS Engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine) which is more or less ACS for Kubernetes now.

As for the access to the blob storage, you dont have to use Managed Service Identity, you can just use account name\key ( which is a bit less secure, but a lot less error prone and more examples exist ). The fact that you are getting `resource not found` error most likely means your auth part is fine, you just dont have access to the resource, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal) storage blob contributor should be fine if you assigned it at a proper scope. For this to work 100% just give your identity contributor access at subscription level, this way its guaranteed to work.

I've found an example of using python with MSI ([here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resource-manager-python-manage-resources-with-msi)). You should start with that (and grant your identity contributor access) and verify you can list resource groups. when that works making reading blobs working should be trivial.

Comment: thanks for your, answer! I'm trying to avoid having to use the storage account key because that would mean hardcoding a credential within my code - something I'm definitely not doing at a production level (should be fine for the dev/staging environment though).
I've been fiddling around with the scope of the permission and where to attach it (service principal / managed identity), but nothing seemed to work so far. the manage identity binding is at least happening successfuly as per events logged within the MIC pod.

Comment: this is what I was missing! :) I was trying too hard to reproduce what I was doing in AWS through permissions/roles - and it just doesn't seem to work the same way here. adding the key through a `Secret` (or through a `ConfigMap` - equivalent to my `server-config.json`) has solved my problems. thanks again!

Comment: well, using MSI would be more in line with what you were doing, but secrets work as well :) do bear in mind secrets are not actually secret anybody with proper permissions can list their contents